# min-height and min-width not working well

Tags: css

hello all I have this `markup`

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

And this `css` File

```
    #content{
    width:100%;
    min-width:1024px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
#left{
    width:15%;
    height:100%;
    min-width:260px;
    float:left;
    outline:1px solid white;
}
#main{
    width:85%;
    height:100%;
    min-width:764px;
    display:inline-block;
    outline:1px solid green;
}
```

when I Resize window Main div brake and start new line, I want that when I resize window `left` and `main` `div` was one line inside `content` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo:**http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/8gbB2/

The Problem Is with **Inline Block**. In Css inline elements are like characters, and characters have spaces among them that are directly derived from their **font size**.

So if you simply put font-size to 0. It will not break like that. Also, assuming this is the whole code. For height to work you should also put something like this:

`html, body {height:100%;}`

```
.cont { min-width: 500px; font-size: 0; height: 500px;}
.left, .main {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}

.left { width: 20%; background-color: red; }
.main { width: 80%; background-color: blue;  }
```

2nd thing that i want to point out...is that you are defining widths two times..which is pointless as only last one is taken into consideration and it cancels the previous one. 
`min-width` and `width` properties will cancel each other depending on which one is defined latest.

Answer (score 1):

`#content`'s parent needs to have a specific height. [Without a parent width / height in your original css, it breaks because it doesn't have a height or width to base off of.](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/y882s/)

If you remove the percentage based dimensions and give it a set dimension it's children float correctly. As seen here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/y882s/1/)

```
#content{
    min-width:1024px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps you.

As you have give `float: left` to `#left` just remove `display: inline-block` amd add `margin-left:15%;` to `#main`

and remove outline for both the `div's`

CSS

```
  #content{
    width:100%;
    min-width:1024px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
#left{
    width:15%;
    height:100%;
    min-width:260px;
    float:left;
    background: #000
}
#main{
    margin-left:15%;
    height:100%;
  background: #ccc
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LHGrB

Comment: But when `#left` is 260px ?

Comment: Give margin-left: 260px to #main